# How can I use execute method in between Queries?

Tags: mysql

**Not able to run execute() method.**

Below is the query:

```mysql
set updateQuery = 'UPDATE `online_token_tracking_info` tti
                        SET tti.fieldName = \'Y\';
                        Where tti.mobileNumber = mobile_number;';

IF  (mobile_count != 0)
THEN
execute(updateQuery);
END IF;
```

I am trying to run it but it throws syntax error. I know it is because of the execute method. Please suggest a query that would help me.

Comment: mysql doesn't like \'Y\';   the semicolon is wrrong at that position and i really don't get what you try to accomplish with \'Y\' what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I was trying the run  set x = 'y' . Since a string won't accept single quotes within single quotes, i had to add back slashes to add those single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
set @updateQuery = CONCAT("UPDATE online_token_tracking_info
                        SET fieldName = 'Y'
                        Where mobileNumber = '", mobile_number,"'");

IF  (mobile_count != 0)
THEN
prepare myStmt from @updateQuery;
execute myStmt;
END IF;
```